# jQuery post script issue in Spring MVC

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc

**SCRIPT**

```
jQuery.post(arr[0] + "/signcap/root/savesignature",
    {
    imageBase64: image_content,
    pdf: pdf_hidden,
    pdevname: pdev_hidden
    },
    function (data, status) {
        if (status == 'success') {
            alert("Success");
        }
    ).done(function(){
        alert("done");
    }).fail(function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert("failed");
    }).complete(function() {
        alert("completed");
    });
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/savesignature", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String saveBlog(
    @RequestParam String imageBase64,
    @RequestParam String pdf,
    @RequestParam String pdevname) throws IOException { ... }
```

Aug 30, 2017 11:22:43 AM

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported
WARNING: Request method 'POST' not supported
```

I keep getting this message and won't proceed further.
Note : I won't not able to use 'get' since the image_content size is really huge.

How can I make it work ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Answer by myself :
In spring-security.xml,  should be disabled(commented) to use POST method.